# How to ssh on multiple ipaddress and get the output and error on the local *nix machine?

Tags: ssh, shell-script, io-redirection

```
command="ls -lrt;uname -a;uname -o"
for i in 10.38.227.229 10.38.164.103
do
ssh auto21@$i "$command 2>&1" >> log
#ssh -n auto21@$i "$command" 2> >> log
done
```

i am trying multiple things but nothing seems to work i get the remote output of only the first ip

in the log file

Comment: I tried your example and get the output for both systems in the log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the `2>&1` on the remote machine. So you're actually doing:

```
ssh auto21@$1 'ls -lrt;uname -a;uname -o 2>&1' >> log
```

Which means you're only redirecting the stderr of the last `uname` command.

Write it:

```
command="ls -lrt;uname -a;uname -o"
for i in 10.38.227.229 10.38.164.103
do
  ssh "auto21@$i" "$command"
done >> log 2>&1
```

ssh does use two channels for transferring stdout and stderr, so the remote commands stderr will end up on `ssh`'s stderr. Above we merge the whole loop (and so ssh) stderr into stdout into `log`.

Or write it:

```
command="ls -lrt;uname -a;uname -o"
for i in 10.38.227.229 10.38.164.103
do
  ssh "auto21@$i" "{ $command; } 2>&1"
done >> log
```

That is have stderr merged into stdout at the remote end, but for all the commands, not just the last one. Or alternatively:

```
  ssh "auto21@$i" "exec 2>&1; $command"
```